# session_destroy() not working when called from angular

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm calling a logout.php page from angular:

```
$scope.logout = function(){
        $cookies.remove("isLoggedIn");
        $http({ url : "./include/logout.php" }).then(function(response) {
alert(response.data)});
        window.open("indexB.html", "_self");
            }
```

Here's the php:

```
<?php
        echo 'test';
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        session_unset();
        unset($_SESSION); 
?>
```

When I click my logout button and call the logout function my "isLoggedIn" cookie is deleted and I get the 'test' alert but the PHP session cookie will not delete.

Comment: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: I created a file called start.php which runs before any html is output to the browser, starts the session, then redirects to the page which is calling the logout function.I'm still seeing the  and session_destroy() still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda had the same problem some time ago, what fixed my problems was:

```
$domain = "yourdomainhere.com";
session_start();
$session = session_id(); 
setcookie("userid", $session, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain what this is doing an how that replaces the typical php session? Can I securely store a userID in this cookie?